# Can you use multiple columns for a not in query?

Tags: sql, mysql, syntax

I recently saw someone post this as part of an answer to an SO query question:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c 
FROM t1 
WHERE (a,b,c) NOT IN 
   ( SELECT DISTINCT a,b,c FROM t2 )
```

I'm a bit confused, as I always thought that you can't use multiple columns for "NOT IN" ("**where(a,b,c)**", etc.). Is this correct SQL syntax? And how about MySQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a SQL extension. Oracle, PostgreSQL and MySQL have it. SQL Server 2005 does not have it. I'm not sure about others.

Answer (score 7):

Googling it suggests that it will work on some databases but not others. You can use this instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c 
FROM t1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT 1 FROM t2 
    WHERE t1.a = t2.a AND t1.b = t2.b AND t1.c = t2.c)
```

Answer (score 3):

It certainly does work in Oracle.  Quick contrived example:

```
SQL> select ename, job, deptno from emp
  2  where (ename, deptno) in
  3  ( select ename, deptno from emp
  4    where job = 'MANAGER'
  5  );

ENAME      JOB           DEPTNO
---------- --------- ----------
JONES      MANAGER           20
CLARK      MANAGER           10
PARAG      MANAGER           30
```

This also works:

```
SQL> select ename, job, deptno from emp
  2  where (ename, deptno) in (('JONES',20),('CLARK',10));

ENAME      JOB           DEPTNO
---------- --------- ----------
JONES      MANAGER           20
CLARK      MANAGER           10
```

NOT IN too:

```
SQL> select ename, job, deptno from emp
  2  where (ename, deptno) not in
  3  ( select ename, deptno from emp
  4    where job = 'MANAGER'
  5  );

ENAME      JOB           DEPTNO
---------- --------- ----------
SMITH      CLEANER           99
SCOTT      ANALYST           20
KING       PRESIDENT         10
FORD       ANALYST           20
MILLER     CLERK             10
```

Comment: He is asking about 'NOT IN'.  Not just 'IN'

Comment: @David Oneill - can't you assume that if one works, so does the other?

Comment: Added NOT IN example just to be sure!

Comment: @froadie, no, you can't assume that.  Or at least, I wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of, but if thy're character type (or can be converted to char types), you can fake it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c  
FROM t1  
WHERE a+b+c NOT IN  
   ( SELECT DISTINCT a+b+c FROM t2 )
```

Comment: This has a bug in it.  a='ab' b='cd' c='ef' will match with a='abcd' b='e' c='f'...

Comment: You'd need to be careful to make sure you don't get collisions based on column content.  I'd put in separators so that columns aren't run together accidentally resulting in false positives: 'a' + 'bb' + 'c" == 'ab' + 'b' + 'c'

Comment: Won't work for certain strings though... a+b could be "abc" for a="ab" and b="c", or a="a" and b="bc".

Comment: Yeah, yeah, yeah... I was going to mention that, but since it was just a hack, I went for the quick solution.

Comment: You can add the separator that don't exist in those fields, between those fields.
I suggest CHAR(0), and be careful for null values :
SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c  
FROM t1  
WHERE a+CHAR(0)+b+CHAR(0)+c NOT IN  
   ( SELECT DISTINCT a+CHAR(0)+b+CHAR(0)+c FROM t2 )

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c  
FROM t1,
(SELECT DISTINCT a,b,c FROM t2) as tt
WHERE t1.a NOT IN tt.a
AND t1.b NOT IN tt.b
AND t1.c NOT IN tt.c
```

Note: This has not been tested, it hasn't even been proven correct.

Comment: My question isn't how to do it - I know of a couple of ways. I just wanted to know if the syntax was correct, as someone posted it and no one objected.

Comment: @froadie Pardon my, misunderstanding.  Other people have answered your question correctly I see.

Answer (score 0):

Others have already answered the question, but as a performance suggestion, if you're dealing with data of any significant size always use the EXISTS statement rather than IN.  It will be faster in almost every case.

http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/01/21/32/