# Exclude rows based on multiple columns from select query

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbi

I have a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE public.mytable (
  p_id varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  j_id varchar(48) NOT NULL,
  u_id varchar(255) NOT NULL
);
```

I'm using the following to find rows based on p_id and j_id:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE p_id = ? AND j_id = ? LIMIT 10
```

I want to extend this query so that it also excludes some rows, for example, I have a list like this:

```
class MyEntity {
    public p_id 
    public j_id;
    public u_id;
}

List<MyEntity> rowsToExclude = new ArrayList<>();
rowsToExclude.add(new MyEntity(1, 3, 5));
rowsToExclude.add(new MyEntity(7, 8, 9));
```

How do I feed the `rowsToExclude` into the query, maybe using a NOT IN?

For example, (not real code), something like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE p_id = ? AND j_id = ? 
AND NOT IN(rowsToExclude)
LIMIT 10
```

Related:

[Select NOT IN multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033604/select-not-in-multiple-columns)

[Can you use multiple columns for a not in query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252626/can-you-use-multiple-columns-for-a-not-in-query)

Comment: Use the primary key to filter out rows. Does the table have a PK?

Comment: Table has no primary key

Comment: LIMIT-ing without ORDER-ing rarely makes sense.

Comment: The rows will be deleted after being fetched, this is done in a loop until all rows are deleted, so I don't think an ORDER BY is needed here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use eight parameters instead of just two.

For example, you can do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE p_id = ? AND j_id = ?
  and (p_id, j_id, u_id) not in ((?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?))
LIMIT 10
```

I would assume `1`, `3`, `5`, `7`, `8`, and `9` are strings since the table columns are `VARCHAR`.

**Note**: This strategy doesn't work with nulls.

Comment: Thanks, any chance you know how to do this using the jdbi fluent api like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55921388/12177456